# Draw line in Excel is not accurate (two monitors)

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code to draw lines in Excel, however, it only works in my main monitor. I mean, if I move the excel to the secondary monitor and run the macro, the lines aren't in the point they should be.

For example, this screenshot is the macro run in the main monitor:
[image]

While this one has been run in the secondary monitor:
[image]

The only difference I can see is that the main monitor has a zoom (windows scale) of 150%, while the secondary monitor is 100%. Is this the reason why is not functioning properly? If so, does anyone know how to solve it?

This is the code I'm using:

```
Sub DrawLine(rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range)
      
    Dim Xstart As Single
    Dim Ystart As Single
    Dim Xend As Single
    Dim Yend As Single
            
    Xstart = rngStart.Left + rngStart.Width / 2
    Ystart = rngStart.Top + (rngStart.Height / 2)
    Xend = rngEnd.Left + rngEnd.Width / 2
    Yend = rngEnd.Top + rngEnd.Height / 2

    
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(Xstart, Ystart, Xend, Yend).Line
        .DashStyle = msoLineSingle
        .Weight = 1.75
        .Transparency = 0.5
    End With
 
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I use a laptop which is connected to the monitor by a dock. Could be that the reason why this is happening?

Comment: Excel is not really designed to be used in this way. Why not just create a chart/graph with the data?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "not designed to be used in this way"?
I've tried a graph but couldn't paint what I need, that's why :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce this, works for me on my main monitor (100%) and on the laptop monitor (150%). Are you sure you are passing the correct cells from the correct worksheet as parameter?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-scaling-issues-for-high-dpi-devices-508483cd-7c59-0d08-12b0-960b99aa347d

Comment: @FunThomas, yes, the cells are ok. I run the same macro, but the "painting" changes when I run it in the primary vs secondary monitor.

Comment: @braX, thanks for the link, unfortunately, I cannot understand it, I'm affraid my knowledge is not enough. Do you mind helping me a little bit more? thanks again. Btw, I'm using excel 365 in W10 over a laptop with a Philips monitor as secondary monitor (nothing to do with the Surface Tablet). Is still affecting me?

Comment: Why don't you use an XY scatter graph?

Comment: @Dominique, because I'm not sure that what I want to represent can be done with it. I would need two X axis and one Y axis. On the other hand, painting the line gives me much more customize options. It is not a "normal" graph, it's more a "simulator".